# Sign PSBT for 2 of 3 multisig

Tags: multi-signature, bip174-psbt

Creating an unsigned PSBT:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "1.0",
    "id": "curltest",
    "method": "walletcreatefundedpsbt",
    "params": [
        [
            {
                "txid": "8b7e8c1898d473fe0229d1adf58aca6299df781e0ff77622a6d6f73273322942",
                "vout": 1
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "tb1qv49u5nkg3y3nma4jmhp8ppl5mj4vyyattlhfyh": 0.005
            }
        ],
        0,
        {
            "includeWatching": true,
            "changeAddress": "tb1q3lkrtkwnt0txka5te0gt02vuk47trssaaxvhml",
            "feeRate": 0.0001
        },
        true
    ]
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "result": {
        "psbt": "cHNidP8BAHECAAAAAUIpMnMy99amInb3Dx5435liyor1rdEpAv5z1JgYjH6LAQAAAAD/////AjaaBwAAAAAAFgAUj+w12dNb1mt2i8vQt6mctXyxwh0goQcAAAAAABYAFGVLyk7IiSM99rLdwnCH9NyqwhOrAAAAAAABAP0hAQIAAAAFLYKKRQsSgx1v3UqETLYL4JCJWenWEn1pB7w/Tz96TdMAAAAAAP3///8tgopFCxKDHW/dSoRMtgvgkIlZ6dYSfWkHvD9PP3pN0wIAAAAA/f///1v4E5Wd/iNzkoNsZsQFQPAj2iRHlmxxmnjaPdEa7TEtAQAAAAD9////LYKKRQsSgx1v3UqETLYL4JCJWenWEn1pB7w/Tz96TdMBAAAAAP3///8pCFtwy3cF4hAMEihbDo3FVncbOKOTqx/LaoVTo1y9hwEAAAAA/f///wLOgi4AAAAAABYAFAv2sYJ4ALY+wb56YP2cI99/Y5biQEIPAAAAAAAiACBdKDYRhxYlihF1dZCM7Kobi25NNKylHThp1cWjEjTxDnsVHQABAStAQg8AAAAAACIAIF0oNhGHFiWKEXV1kIzsqhuLbk00rKUdOGnVxaMSNPEOAQVpUiEDe68lJzJ5hEVUKScCjod3qtntXQ9gMg4qa6g2LDMwhVQhAlKXOTSX1IxzZ37WAglDONf6o41uMvUm2k/Oniqutlu6IQNs3xVmKT6xvTJLTc4jB+JwmQmnPSZFCX6JMkA+neL4Q1OuIgYCUpc5NJfUjHNnftYCCUM41/qjjW4y9SbaT86eKq62W7oEN8HtHCIGA2zfFWYpPrG9MktNziMH4nCZCac9JkUJfokyQD6d4vhDBCnQwHAiBgN7ryUnMnmERVQpJwKOh3eq2e1dD2AyDiprqDYsMzCFVARbIBXQACICAuNOa3WDX2adJy31UOYgFUi2M79B12ijzcvzjVTG0mbsEJGMV+YAAACAAAAAgAcAAIAAAA==",
        "fee": 0.00001770,
        "changepos": 0
    },
    "error": null,
    "id": "curltest"
}
```

The UTXO that I am trying to spend is 2 of 3 multisig address: `tb1qt55rvyv8zcjc5yt4wkggem92rw9kunf54jj36wrf6hz6xy357y8qgpk8xa`

I created multisig with this request:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "1.0",
    "id": "curltest",
    "method": "createmultisig",
    "params": [
        2,
        [
            "037baf252732798445542927028e8777aad9ed5d0f60320e2a6ba8362c33308554",
            "025297393497d48c73677ed602094338d7faa38d6e32f526da4fce9e2aaeb65bba",
            "036cdf1566293eb1bd324b4dce2307e2709909a73d2645097e8932403e9de2f843"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Address was added to wallet using this request:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "1.0",
    "id": "curltest",
    "method": "importmulti",
    "params": [
        [
            {
                "desc": "sh(multi(2,037baf252732798445542927028e8777aad9ed5d0f60320e2a6ba8362c33308554,025297393497d48c73677ed602094338d7faa38d6e32f526da4fce9e2aaeb65bba,036cdf1566293eb1bd324b4dce2307e2709909a73d2645097e8932403e9de2f843))#t9xkhn5c",
                "timestamp": "now",
                "label": "gg1936",
                "watchonly": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Now I want to use the unsigned PSBT and sign it. Which RPC call should be used for it and what should I mention in arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you want to use is `walletprocesspsbt`. The only argument you need is the PSBT itself.

Comment: How will you do it if the 3 public keys are in different wallets? Will the same command be used 2 times in 2 different wallets?

Comment: Yes. For each wallet, you use the same RPC. Just each time use the PSBT given by the previous wallet.

Comment: @percy-g2 did it work for you?